In which configuration file is the Sitecore 9.3.0 Marketing Automation process default schedule interval defined (10 minutes)
I'm getting an error in an Azure production environment where the MarketingAutomation CheckoutCommand is timing out. It seems to be related to the issues here:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001377
However, all I want to know is where the MarketingAutomation task is being scheduled to run every 10 minutes. That is what configuration files controls it's scheduled runs, it's timeout values, retries and where errors like this would occur in the logs.

You can find the setting related to timeout inside the Sitecore Marketing automation role server at the following location.
App_Data/jobs/continuous/AutomationEngine/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/MarketingAutomation/sc.MarketingAutomation.Workers.xml

Inside this file, you can configure timeout for Normal priority workers as below.

In case you would like to create individual pool workers and set the timeout for each one of them individually, that can be set by enabling below config.

In the same file, you can find schedule for marketing plan processing as below.

Similarly details for the retry can be found inside following file.
App_Data/jobs/continuous/AutomationEngine/App_Data/Config/Sitecore/MarketingAutomation/sc.MarketingAutomation.PoolFilter.xml


More details on the same can be found here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-platform/marketing-automation-plan-processing.html#prioritize-work-from-a-particular-channel
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

As per the Sitecore 9.3 documents you can find this setting under the sc.MarketingAutomation.Workers.xml file. Here are the details.

Schedule: Specifies how long the workers sleep when there is no work available (in seconds)

MinimumPriority: Specifies the minimum priority of work items to process

WorkItemTimeout: Specifies hours:minutes:seconds of timeout for a work item

WorkItemTimeoutSchedule: Specifies hours:minutes:seconds before the timeout is reset


<ExplicitPoolWorker1>
    <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Processing.PoolWorker, Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation</Type>
    <As>Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Core.Processing.IPoolWorker, Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Core</As>
    <LifeTime>Transient</LifeTime>
    <Options>
        <Schedule>00:00:20</Schedule>
        <MinimumPriority>0</MinimumPriority>
        <WorkItemTimeout>00:00:10</WorkItemTimeout>
        <WorkItemTimeoutSchedule>00:00:07</WorkItemTimeoutSchedule>
        <BatchHead>3</BatchHead>
        <BatchSize>5</BatchSize>
    </Options>
</ExplicitPoolWorker1>

Kindly refer this document for more details.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/marketing-automation-plan-processing.html
Hope this helps.
